Is there any way to use the angular form without rxjs?
Currently I see that although angular signals already exist in a stable way, even utilities like forms, http client, etc are still using rxjs for change detection, and I wonder if there is a way to use them with angular signals, since they are more comfortable and I don't need to subscribe just to know if the input is now true and have to always be aware of unsubscribing to avoid memory leaks.
If there is already a way, please let me know, if not, do you think it would be a good idea?

You could probably try rxjs-interop. It's not exactly stable, but it could get you going.

Is there a way? Sure, see spartan-signal-forms.
Should you? No, signals are not a complete replacement for RxJS. It's in the name "Reactive" Forms meaning they are powered by and designed around RxJS.
Last alternative would be template forms. Template forms are a slightly more "bare metal" way to interact with forms which allows you to more easily mix-and-match paradigms. I honestly don't see the value though as I consider template forms best left for dead-simple forms/controls that don't need any features offered by something like reactive forms.
